Cannot get pylance to properly typecheck variable in extended class
Here's my setup simplified:
from abc import ABC
from typing import TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel

_M = TypeVar("_M", bound=BaseModel)

class A(BaseModel):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3

class Base(ABC):
    cfg_model: type[_M]

    def __init__(self):
        self.cfg = self.cfg_model()

class ChildA(Base):
    cfg_model = A
    
    def run(self):
        self.cfg_model  # (variable) model_class: type[_M]
        self.cfg        # (variable) cfg: _M

        # pylance fails to detect properties in `self.cfg`
        self.cfg.a
        self.cfg.b
        self.cfg.c

The idea is that there are multiple classes extending the base abstract class, each having it's own config model.
But i can't seem to figure out how to make pylance (i'm using Visual Studio Code) correctly typecheck self.cfg in ChildA's run method as A.
UPD: Turning Base into generic class helped:
from abc import ABC
from typing import TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel

_M = TypeVar("_M", bound=BaseModel)

class A(BaseModel):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3

class Base(ABC, Generic[_M]):
    cfg_model: type[_M]

    def __init__(self):
        self.cfg = self.cfg_model()

class ChildA(Base[A]):
    cfg_model = A
    
    def run(self):
        self.cfg_model  # (variable) model_class: type[A]
        self.cfg        # (variable) cfg: A

        # all properties are correctly typechecked
        self.cfg.a
        self.cfg.b
        self.cfg.c

However, it irks me that i need to provide the Model name twice (in class argument and in class variable). Can this be avoided somehow?

If you were to use strict mode (place # pyright: strict at the top of the file), you would receive an error saying cfg_model: type[_M] is invalid because Base is not generic. Also, you have a typo: it's cgf in Base but cfg in ChildA.

Thanks, the typo was last minute edit, so it wasn't affecting my setup. # pyright: strict however did brought up a few errors, although it was "Type variable "_M" has no meaning in this context" for line cfg_model: type[_M]. Turning Base into generic class did allow for typechecking to work, altough there is one little thing that bother me (see update).

In that case, there are a few possible duplicates: How to access the type arguments of typing.Generic?, Generic[T] base class - how to get type of T from within instance?.

Thanks, combination of __init_subclass__ and __orig_bases__ did help. Just to make sure, it's impossible to infer type of the self.cfg without using Generic, right? The thing is, some children may not need cfg_model (i guess i can extend _M to support None, but i was thinking that class variables would look nicer).

If you have a new question, I suggest posting it as such with a [mre]. I'm not sure what your code would look like, so I can't tell whether it is possible or not.
